# Custom numpy installation failing in UNIX

Tags: python, linux, numpy, pip, installation

I am trying to perform a specific custom installation using below command:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=/apps/TDM/software/py" --no-dependencies numpy
```

but it is failing with below error.

```
/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-w48fsczg/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace
('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-bxo1rvl_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --prefix=/apps/TDM/software/p
y" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-w48fsczg/numpy/
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Also I cannot upgrade PIP as I do not have assess to `/opt` layer.

Comment: `man errno` says that error 1 is EPERM, i.e. permission error. Do you have write access to the stated prefix? Can you set the prefix to a directory which is in your home directory or something like that?

Comment: I have access to "/apps/TDM/software/py" directory, can you please tell which directory I need to ave access to ? Is it "/tmp/pip-build-w48fsczg/numpy/" but this looks like a temp directory thats getting created

Comment: I don't really know. /tmp is writable by all users so I don't see a problem there. My advice is to try again with prefix set a directory in your home directory. You might also consider installing a newer version of pip to your home directory (this is sometimes called a local installation).